# error expected an indented block in my docstring

Tags: python

During the run time to check my class, I received an indentation error

```
class Category:
"""
Creates category class, possible child class of products
Parameters
­­­­­­­­­­
name : str, default blank
Desired name of category
category_type : str, default blank
type of category
model : int , default 0 
model of category in years
"""
#Declaring __init__()Function
def __init__(self,name="",category_type="",model=0):
  self.name = name
  self.category_type = category_type
  self.model = model
  print (name,"Created!") # Run when init is finished.
#Declaring print_status()Function
def print_status(self):
  print("Category :",self.name,"\n category type :"self.category_type,"\n Model :"self.model)

p1 = Category("Iphone","Technology",2020)
p1.print_status()
```

the error message :
File "", line 13
"""

^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: `def` needs to be indented inside the `class`

Comment: no indentation under the class definition breaks out of the class definition, so really all your telling the interpreter is `class Category:` before breaking out...a class needs at least a `pass` to be valid..all your class methods need to be indented under the class definition (and the docstring too)

Answer (score 1):

Just indent every line in your class (up to the line `print("Category :....")`).

Python should know when the class starts and when it stops. And it knows that with indentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_status(self):
  print("Category :",self.name,"\n category type :"self.category_type,"\n Model :"self.model)
```

It seems you are missing a comma before self.Model in the above statement.

Comment: Indentation error will be solved by doing what @limserhane suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A docstring, as its name suggests, is a string literal. Since it is not a comment, it follows the same indentation requirements as any other code in the body of the class (i.e. it must be indented).

Here's a related question with more detail: [IndentationError from comment in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11860064)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
class Category:
  """
  Creates category class, possible child class of products
  Parameters
  ­­­­­­­­­­
  name : str, default blank
  Desired name of category
  category_type : str, default blank
  type of category
  model : int , default 0
  model of category in years
  """
  #Declaring __init__()Function
  def __init__(self,name="",category_type="",model=0):
    self.name = name
    self.category_type = category_type
    self.model = model
    print (name,"Created!") # Run when init is finished.
  #Declaring print_status()Function
  def print_status(self):
    print("Category :",self.name,"\n category type :", self.category_type,"\n Model :", self.model)
```

**Discussion**:

The `def` statements need to be indented relative to the `class` statement, just as the body of the `def`s are indented relative to the first line of the `defs`.

Independently, your `print` statement in the last line of your class contains syntax errors. I fixed them by inserting commas between arguments of `print`. Now, while I can vouch that my changes make your class free of syntax errors, I can't guarantee that it prints what you want it to print. I suggest that you test that.